# how/where to catch the Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

Using the new Android Architecture components it can help to trigger the observer’s method when lifecycle change.

If would like to do something at the lifeCycle’s Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE, how to catch it?

Since the getLifecycle().addObserver(new MyLifecycleObserver(//..)); is added in the activity's onCreate(), the Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE should have been passed?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //..
        getLifecycle().addObserver(new MyLifecycleObserver(//..));

    }
}



public class MyLifecycleObserver implements LifecycleObserver {

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
void onCreate() {
    //..
}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
void onStart() {}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
void onStop() {}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
void onPause() {}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
void onResume() {}
//..
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. I put a simple `Log.d()` in `MyLifecycleObserver`'s `onCreate()`, and the message was outputted to logcat.

Answer (score 0):

the [video](https://academy.realm.io/posts/360-andev-2017-yigit-boyar-android-architecture-components/) explained it.  the activity's onStart() ... to OnResume() are called first the the ones on LifeCycle's;  when moving towards destroying,  onStop() ... onDestroy(), the LifeCycle's get called first then the activity's.
the video `https://academy.realm.io/posts/360-andev-2017-yigit-boyar-android-architecture-components/`